# `bundle install` saves parameters in the config file, can it be prevented?

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler

Documentation for `bundle config` says that a configuration file is necessary for remembering options such as `--path` or `--without`.

I find that when I run `bundle install --without some-group` or `BUNDLE_WITHOUT=some-group bundle install`, my `.bundle/config` file has a new line, namely:

```
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "some-group"
```

I would like be able to install without a certain group yet not have a new line in `.bundle/config`.

This is inconvenient because `.bundle/config` is naturally under source control, but I have two development environments, one where `some-group` can be installed and one where it can't.

I don't want developers to see untracked modifications in their git status when they develop in the platform where an environment variable `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` is set.

Recommendations?

Comment: The `.bundle` directory is usually excluded from version control.

Comment: To elaborate on @Kris's comment, the official bundler documentation states ["Do not check in the .bundle directory, or any of the files inside it. Those files are specific to each particular machine, and are used to persist installation options between runs of the bundle install command."](https://bundler.io/rationale.html#checking-your-code-into-version-control)